# Angular post can't pass parameter to Asp.Net MVC

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to execute a POST from my angular application to a Asp.Net MVC Controller but I cannot send parameters. It seems null.  When I make a POST request on Postman, it successfully makes the POST request.

Controller:

```
  public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public ActionResult Index(PersonModel person)
    {
        int? personId = person.PersonId;
        string name = person.Name;
        string gender = person.Gender;
        string city = person.City;

        return View();
    }
```

I tried the following but it didn't work:

1. Content-type:'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
2. Content-type:'application/json; charset=utf-8'
3. headers not exists: 
   this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:62918/', person
   ).subscribe(..)
4. JSON.stringify --> this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:62918/', JSON.stringify(person).subscribe(..)

angular 8:

```
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
};
const person = {PersonId: 2, Gender: 'M', City: 'New York', Name: 'Adam'};
this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:62918/', person, httpOptions ).subscribe(
  (res) => console.log("res:", res),
);
```

POSTMAN - fiddler request Raw:

POST http://localhost:62918/ HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.23.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: aa404f5f-4e52-4a95-91e4-dc3037c4b1df
Host: localhost:62918
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Length: 83
Connection: keep-alive

{
    PersonId: 2,
    Name: 'Adam',
    Gender: 'M',
    City: 'New York'
  }

Comment: Regarding your routing, seems you are missing the controller and possibly action after the host. Example: `http://localhost:62918/Person/Update`  or `http://localhost:62918/Person` or `http://localhost:62918/api/Person` etc. It depends how you have your routing setup.

Comment: What exactly is `null`? Is it the property values or the `person` parameter entirely? How are you debugging to ensure that this end point is actually called as opposed to some other end point.

Comment: When I debugging server side  I see person is null (in index action), It is Asp.Net MVC application (not web api)

Comment: Are you sending the exact same json string in Postman or is the casing different on the properties?

Comment: Does it help if you use the `[FromBody]` attribute on your PersonModel parameter? Like this: `public ActionResult Index([FromBody] PersonModel person)`

Comment: Use the debug console in your browser to review the http post request and compare that to the request made from postman. There is a difference, this should help you find it.